# Entity Framework MVC and "static" objects from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table in my database, where I put states of USA (just ID and state name).

I want to get these values in my controler - shall I do standard operations: add context in my EF, later get objects? Or there is another way to get it?

I don't want to make any changes in this table, so db.XYZ.Add, db.XYZ.SaveChanges() etc. methods is not important for me.

What is the best practise to get objects like "states" or for example base of "zip codes"?

Later, second question: what means "virtual" in code like this:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    (..)
    public virtual string UserType { get; set; }
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework allows getting objects from the database without adding them to the change tracker:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var states = db.States.AsNoTracking();
    ...
}
```

However, when you use a `State` object in a reference, e.g. like:

```
var address = new Address() { State = state1 };
db.Addresses.Add(address);
db.SaveChanges();
```

where `state1` is a `State` object, `state1` will be attached to the context after all and have `EntityState.Added`!

So you should still be careful how to use these "untracked" objects. In this example you'd better set a primitive `StateId` property:

```
var address = new Address() { StateId = state1.Id };
```

(does not attach `state1`).

What you'd really want in this case is preventing EF from ever changing the `EntityState` of a `State` object. There is no way I can think of to enforce this. Would be an interesting feature.

---

> what means "virtual" in code like this

The `virtual` modifier is commonly used to enable lazy loading of navigation properties. `Address` could have

```
public virtual State State { get; set; }
```

Now when you grab an address from the database and afterwards access its `State` property, the state is loaded from the database at that moment. This is because under the hood EF creates an `Address` object that is a derivative of your `Address` class and that has overridden the `State` property with code that enables lazy loading.

However, in the code you show `virtual` has no bearing on lazy loading because it is a string property. So it can't be a navigation property and it does not allow lazy loading.

Comment: thanks ! Can you show me more articles about `virtual` in EF? This topic is still unclear for me. Especially `lazy loading` - I don't understand this. Some example will be very helpfull for me:) Regards!

Comment: hmm a litle bit more understandable, but still unclear. How EF know in `Eagerly Loading` which `Posts` have to load in `Include`? The same question in `Lazy Loading` - as I understood, when I get for example `Blog` from database, I will also automaticly get `Posts` connected with this blog - am I right? But how it is possible? How EF knows which `Posts` connected with `virtual ICollection<Post> Posts `

Comment: That's what the object-relational _mapping_ is for, which code-first carries out under the hood by adopting a number of standard naming and association conventions.

Comment: ok, but am I right in my previous comment? Shall I do some `mapping` for tables and objects (for example `postId` property in `Topics` and connect it with table `Post`? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In code first I use an enums to save items with an int id and description.

To do it this way I add the following:

In the user add:

```
...

public int StateId { get; set; }

public State State
{
   get { return (State)StateId ; }
}
...
```

Create an enum:

```
public enum State
{
    State1,
    State2
}
```

The enum Id is saved back as a `StateId` to the `User` each time I save a user.

Answer (score 0):

[On this link you can find more about "virtual" in your code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

To get all states you can easy do this:

```
var getStates = from i in db.States select i;
```

and of course you can add some conditions if you want.